# systemd network service does not work?

Tags: networking, interface, systemd

Today, I install ubuntu 16.04 in my machine.
When I boot the system, I can not get the IP address from DHCP server.
The network interface is renamed to enp2s0 from eth0.
I only get the IP address after run command:

```
$ sudo ethtool -s enp2s0 autoneg off speed 100
```

I try to add this command in init script (/etc/rc.local) but it does not work after I reboot system.

So, from now, when my machine is booted, I always need to add the above command mannually to get IP address.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ubuntu, use command line and execute the following:

$ sudo crontab -e

and add your script that you want to execute upon restarts by adding this at the end:

@reboot ethtool -s enp2s0 autoneg off speed 100

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

systemd considers both "rc.local" and "crontabs" to be "legacy". It has replacements for both. However, Ubuntu 16.04 supports both concepts.

I think your issue is that now `rc.local` is run before the network is fully online, causing your command to fail.

Look at `/lib/systemd/system/rc.local.service` to see how `systemd` is running your rc.local file. In particular note that the line `After=network.target`.

Try creating this file:

`/etc/systemd/systemd/rc.local.service.d/10-wait-for-network.conf`

Add these lines to it:

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target
```

Then reboot and see if that works for you.

References:

- [Force services to wait for the network to be configured](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2014/10/linux-tip-force-systemd-networkd-to-wait-for-dhcp.html)
- [Using systemd Drop-In units](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html)

Also, in the future SO is not the best place for `systemd` questions. Consider http://askubuntu.com for Ubuntu question instead.

I'll also add that the behavior change you found might be considered a bug in how Ubuntu emulates `rc.local` support with `systemd`. If the proposed fix works, perhaps Ubuntu shoudl change the `rc.local` replacement to load after `network-online` instead of `network`.